# Discord.py No output when using the message

Tags: discord, discord.py

Its purpose is to limit server members from spamming the message, but is still used when needed. However, when I try using it nothing is sent on discord nor is there an error message from the terminal side. I don't have get syntax errors either. I have also tried using an `or` statement instead of an `and` statement in the `if` condition but this didn't work either. Any solution is appreciated, thanks in advance.

```py
import discord
import random
import datetime
from discord import Embed
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents(messages = True, guilds = True, reactions = True, members = True, presences = True)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '*', intents = intents)
    
class PleaseWork(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.last_timeStamp = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        time_difference = (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - self.last_timeStamp).total_seconds()
        if time_difference < 5 and message.author == client.user:
            return

        elif message.content.startswith('yo lebclan'): 
            await message.channel.send('Sup?')
            self.last_timeStamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you loading the cog? That might be why nothing shows up, it's because you aren't actually running the code so it doesn't tell you anything.

This helped me a lot when I was having the same issue:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQw8cFfZPx0&list=PLW3GfRiBCHOhfVoiDZpSz8SM_HybXRPzZ&index=7

The first part with the loading and unloading might be what you need.